# How to load intersections consolidated graphs

Tags: python, openstreetmap, osmnx

To get the right connected components, I projected a graph then use 'osmnx.simplification.consolidate_intersections' to consolidate intersections.

```
import osmnx as ox
import pandas as pd
import networkx as nx 
%matplotlib inline
cities = {'Copenhagen':'Copenhagen Municipality, Denmark'}

G1=ox.graph.graph_from_place('Copenhagen Municipality, Denmark', simplify=False, retain_all=True, truncate_by_edge=True, which_result=None, buffer_dist=None,clean_periphery=True, custom_filter='["highway"~"cycleway"]')

G11=ox.simplification.consolidate_intersections(ox.project_graph(G1, to_crs='EPSG:3812'), tolerance=15, rebuild_graph=True, dead_ends=True, reconnect_edges=True)
G2==ox.project_graph(G11, to_crs='EPSG:4326')

ox.io.save_graphml(G2, filepath='data/Copenhagen_bike.graphml', gephi=True, encoding='utf-8')
print('Copenhagen bike_net saved')
```

Then comes the question:
I saved G1 as GraphML file, but when I tried to load Copenhagen_bike.graphml, it would come error
" ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '14-1' ". I wonder how to load the file to get a graph with no error.

Anyone who offers help will be appreciated.

Comment: crosspost: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/394708/loading-intersections-consolidated-graphs

Answer (score 1):

This was a bug in OSMnx. It was recently [fixed](https://github.com/gboeing/osmnx/issues/647) and will appear in the next [release](https://github.com/gboeing/osmnx/issues/655), targeted for early May 2021.